# Template routes and Pagination - blank page

Tags: templates, pagination, template-routes

I've got a blog listing template where pagination is not working as expected. I see the pagination links but when I follow one I get taken to a blank page.

My template routes are:

[image]

All links from listing template to single template work except for pagination links. I've also tried turning the blog/index tempalte to require segments but that also did not work

My blog listing template is:

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="2" dynamic="yes"}
                <article class="post">
                    <div class="media">
                      <a class="pull-right" href="#">
                        {exp:ce_img:single src="{blog_image}" width="290" height="113" add_dims="no" attributes="class='media-object'"}
                      </a>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{route="blog/single" blog-post="{url_title}"}">{title}</a></h4>

                        {if blog_copy:has_excerpt}
                            <p>{blog_copy:excerpt text_only="yes"}&hellip;</p>
                        {if:else}
                            {exp:eehive_hacksaw
                                words = "25" 
                                append = "&hellip;"
                                allow="<p><b><a>"}
                                {blog_copy}
                            {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
                        {/if} 

                        <a href="{route="blog/single" blog-post="{url_title}"}" class="readMore">Read More</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </article>


                {paginate}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    {pagination_links}
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            {!--
                            {first_page}
                                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
                            {/first_page}
                            --}

                            {previous_page}
                                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a></li>
                            {/previous_page}

                            {page}
                                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
                            {/page}

                            {next_page}
                                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                            {/next_page}

                            {!--
                            {last_page}
                                <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
                            {/last_page}
                            --}
                        </ul>
                    {/pagination_links}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/paginate}



            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm an idiot - forgot to put /blog/ in the template route for blog/index so it should be /blog/{pagination}

Why do I always find the solution minutes after posting? Why?

Comment: This has given me hope for how to go from page 1 (1st template entry list) to page 2 (2nd template entry list onwards) using different templates. Thanks for thinking aloud :)